# Username and password authentication using URQL/Apollo-GraphQL in SvelteKit

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, sveltekit, urql

I have a SvelteKit application in which backend is in django-graphene (GraphQL backend). I'm able to send username and password and I am able to get the token from backend. But, how do I setup the token for use in child components. I went through URQL/Apollo-GgraphQL docs but nothing is there to set the token or pass the token.

I tried sending that Token using URQL auth-exchange and also using apollo-graphql client but nothing is working.

If someone has **example** authentication code working using URQL/GraphQL with SvelteKit then please do share.